# Android BLE Glucometer data parsing - Datetime

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on android app which is used to read sugar level from BLE device (Any Glocometer) whenever new data available. I am able to read data from device. Below is the HEX formatted data i received.

0B 04 00 E4 07 05 0E 0C 31 1D 4E 01 68 B0 F8 00 00

Field3: Date Time (54 bits): E4 07 05 0E 0C 31 1D

I am not able to get year from this data, value of E4 is 228 and what about 07
Other data is month, date, hour, minute, second

How to get year from the above datetime data. Any help

Answer (score 0):

For me, it looks like it's 2020 May(or June) 14, 12:49:29. In a case like this wherein the document protocol is not available, we can do some guessing.

07E4 => 2020 - E4 is low byte and 07 is high byte - this is a common practice

05 => May - It's my guess that this is the month. The other numbers are more than 12. It can also be June if 00 represents January

0E => 14 - Since it follows after the month byte, I guess this is the day.

0C => 12 - It's my guess that this is the hour, 49 and 29 can never be the hour value

31 => 49 - minute

1D => 29 - second

This can be verified by getting the actual values in the glucometer and see if it matches to the parsed data.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65458794/10438652) has a very detailed explanation on how to decode the data.

The data format is given at: https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.glucose_measurement.xml

Using this format, what I understood was if we convert your hex (

> 0B 04 00 E4 07 05 0E 0C 31 1D 4E 01 68 B0 F8 00 00

) to binary and then look at it byte by byte, we'll be able to decode the data. For eg. :

(Here I have prepended the binary 1011 with 0000)

Bytes

76543210 : Bit index (Remember Little Endian)

`00001011`   11    | 1 byte (Flag byte) | C1,C2,C5 are present

`00000100`   4   | 2 byte Sequence Number

`00000000`   0   | 4 + (0<<8) = 4   [Because  Little Endian]

`11100100`  228  | 228 + (7<<8) = 228 + (1792) = 2020

`00000111`   7

`00000101`   5   | 1 byte | 5 =  May

`00001110`  14   | 1 byte | 14 = Date

`00001100`  12   | 1 byte | 12 = Hour

`00110001`  49   | 1 byte | 49 = Minute

`00011101`  29   | 1 byte | 29 = seconds

`01001110`  78   | 2 byte | 78 + (1<<8) = 334 Time Offset

`00000001`   1

`01101000`  0.104  | Glucose reading in kg/l

`10110000`       |  SFLOAT datatype of 2 bytes where first 12 bytes are mantissa and next 4 bits give exponent. Therefore 000001101000 = 104 | 1011 = -3. Thereby total value = 104 * 10^-3 = 0.104 kg/mol

`11111000`   | 2 Nibbles (values are 8 and 15)

`00000000`   0   | 7  6  5  4  3  2   1  0  Bit indexes

`00000000`   0   | 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  Bit indexes